# PL/SQL: bind variable does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How to modify this procedure to let it use bind variables

```
PROCEDURE KILL(user IN VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
  FOR REC IN (SELECT sid,serial# serial FROM V$SESSION WHERE username = user)
  LOOP 
    execute immediate 'alter system kill session '' :1 , :2 '' immediate' 
    using rec.sid,  rec.serial; 
    END LOOP; 
END;
```

It gives:

> bind variable does not exist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bind variables in your statement are being treated as literal strings rather than place holders. If you output the statement you're generating:

```
BEGIN
    FOR REC IN (SELECT sid,serial# serial FROM V$SESSION WHERE username = user)
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('alter system kill session '':1,:2'' immediate');
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

... you see lines like:

```
alter system kill session ':1,:2' immediate
```

The `':1,:2'` is treated as a static value and not as two bind variables. You can't use bind variables in dynamic DDL, and I'm not sure if that applies to `alter` commands, so this may be impossible anyway.

The simplest way to achieve this may be to generate the whole statement in the cursor:

```
BEGIN
    FOR REC IN (
        SELECT 'alter system kill session ''' || sid ||','|| serial#
            ||''' immediate' stmt
        FROM V$SESSION WHERE username = user)
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(rec.stmt);
        --execute immediate rec.stmt;
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

With the `execute` commented out (I don't really want to kill my sessions just now) you can just see the commands it will run, like:

```
alter system kill session '58,47157' immediate
```

<strike>Your approach may still be flawed though as it will kill the session that is executing the block, and it may or may not kill it last. I think this is in the realms of undefined behaviour, and I don't really want to try it to find out what happens... I doubt that's what you actually want anyway.</strike>

**Edit:** 'flawed' comment was based on using `user`, which in my anonymous block would be the executing user; in your proc it would be the user from the parameter. Using a keyword as a parameter name is confusing though, so I'd recommend changing the name to something like `p_user`, in the args and the statement.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this might work

```
PROCEDURE KILL(user IN VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
  FOR REC IN (SELECT sid,serial# serial FROM V$SESSION WHERE username = user)
  LOOP 
    execute immediate 'alter system kill session :1 '||','|| ':2 immediate' 
    using rec.sid,  rec.serial; 
    END LOOP; 
END;
```

Comment: The concatenation is superfluous; that's equivalent to `'alter system kill session :1 ,:2 immediate'`. The `alter system kill` syntax needs the `sid` and `serial#` to be passed as a pair in a string, so that isn't a valid command unfortunately. (Docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10595/manproc008.htm) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_2014.htm#i2282145))